# send varint without deleting CodedOutputStream, ZeroCopyOutputStream

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My application sends varints many times. Every time I have to allocate memory for 2 objetcs: CodedOutputStream and FileOutputStream and later relese it. IMO it is unnecessary time loss. How can I send the varint without all this process? (I don't want to do it manually but with protobuf)

---

I have found it:

```
delete coded_output;
  /*  delete raw_output;*/
  ((FileOutputStream*)raw_output)->Flush();
```

but still there is one object to allocate every time

---

```
  void Connection::send(const Message& msg) throw(EmptyMessage) {
    //CodedOutputStream* coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);
    CodedOutputStream coded_output(raw_output);
    int n = msg.ByteSize();
    if(n<=0) throw EmptyMessage();
    //coded_output->WriteVarint32(n);
    coded_output.WriteVarint32(n);
    //delete coded_output;
    coded_output.~CodedOutputStream();
    raw_output->Flush();
    msg.SerializeToArray(buffer, n);
    SocketMaintenance::write(buffer, n);
  }

  Annoucement Connection::receive() throw(EmptySocket) {
    //CodedInputStream* coded_input = new CodedInputStream(raw_input);
    CodedInputStream coded_input(raw_input);
    google::protobuf::uint32 n;
    //coded_input->ReadVarint32(&n);
    coded_input.ReadVarint32(&n);
    char *b;
    int m;
    //coded_input->GetDirectBufferPointer((const void**)&b, &m);
    coded_input.GetDirectBufferPointer((const void**)&b, &m);
    Annoucement ann;
    ann.ParseFromArray(b, n);
    return ann;
  }
```

When I use the code above, I get this error (runtime error) from my client application (this apps uses only the send function):

> libprotobuf FATAL
>   google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:346]
>   CHECK failed: (buffer_used_) ==
>   (buffer_size_):  BackUp() can only be
>   called after Next(). terminate called
>   after throwing an instance of
>   'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>   what():  CHECK failed: (buffer_used_)
>   == (buffer_size_):  BackUp() can only be called after Next(). Stopped

When I use the commented out part of code instead the corresponding one all works fine.

Comment: You're destroying coded_output twice - once explicitly, then again implicitly at the end of the function. I suggest you let it be destroyed at the right time in the usual way - insert open brace immediately before its declaration and replace the explicit destructor call with a close brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to allocate the CodedOutputStream on the heap, you can just declare it as a local variable (or class member) where you need it. It doesn't look like the constructor is particularly expensive.

Are you always writing to the same file? If so you can just use a single CodedOuputStream and FileOutputStream for all the writes.

Comment: I have just tried. I have to delete it before I user FLush from FileOutputStream. Unless I do, I get: _libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:346] CHECK failed: (buffer_used_) == (buffer_size_):  BackUp() can only be called after Next().
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
  what():  CHECK failed: (buffer_used_) == (buffer_size_):  BackUp() can only be called after Next().
Stopped_

Comment: I tried  coded_output.~CodedOutputStream()  instead of delete coded_output but no success.

Comment: I decided to add how it looks into the question.